# Correctly align Divs - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>
    <div align="center" id="cen">+</div>
  </h1>
  <h1>
    <div align="center" class="Area" id="left">1</div>
  </h1>
  <h1>
    <div align="center" class="Phone" id="right">650000</div>
  </h1><br>
</div>
```

[image]

The grey area is my container DIV
The Top is what I have
The bottom is what I want.

Nothing I do sligns them correctly, or pushing one div to the next line. Its so frustrating I'm about to smash my computer

Comment: If the only thing you want is the text to be aligned, why don't you just lay it out as plain HTML, instead of using CSS `float` properties to position it?

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete. https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply use span and some margin:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>+</span><span>1</span><span>650000000</span></h1>
```

you can then change individual margin by adding some class